# Can I delete the forms folder found within a Document Library post Folder Move

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Previously I had 10 document folders which I decided to make all subfolders under a Library folder called "Main".  Thus, I went into Windows Explorer and coped all 10 folders and files to the Main folder.

I notice now though each subfolder correctly has all the associated files, but all 10 subfolders now contain a folder called "Forms".  Can I delete all 10 Forms folders found within each one of these 10 subfolders ?

What is the purpose of this folder called Forms ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Forms*-folder, as the name and the content suggest, contains all the

- *Forms* (for displaying [*DispForm.aspx*], editing [*EditForm.aspx*], uploading [*Upload.aspx*], etc.)
- *Document Template* (by default an empty *template.dotx*)
- *Views* (the *All Items View* [AllItems.aspx], *Thumbnails View* [Thumbnails.aspx] and some helper *Views* [repair.aspx, Combine.aspx]).

[image]

Let's say you create a new *View* for your library and you call that view *MyCustomView*, then you will find another file in the *Forms* folder called *MyCustomView.aspx* containing the definition of your *View*

The *Forms*-folder is usually hidden from both, viewing it on the web and in the file explorer and therefore won't be copied when you copy all documents to a new location. I guess you have the *Show Hidden Items* option activated in your file explorer and thus, you were able to copy the folder.

It is safe to delete the *Forms*-folder from the subfolders at the **NEW** location. The *Document Library* where the files reside now, will use the its own *Forms*-folder located at the root of it.

Answer (score 0):

Hidden forms folder: SharePoint library has a hidden folder called ‘forms’ where the templates and system forms(.ASPX files) like allitems.aspx, editform.aspx, dispform.aspx etc are stored. This folder is not usually visible. It is a hidden folder. If any user has ‘show hidden files and folders’ enabled in windows explorer, forms folder is visible for them.

[image: Forms Folder Contains]

**If You delete this document then you wont be able do such task.**